# Open Command Prompt through scheduler

Tags: command-prompt, scheduler

[image: Details of the batch file][image: The screen shot of the task scheduler]I have a batch process which opens the command prompt and fires some commands on the command prompt. 
Now i am trying to schedule the batch through the windows task scheduler.
When i manually run the batch process , the command prompt is opened and i can see the command in the batch file being executed.
However when i run the scheduler, the status for the scheduler is shown as running, but i am unable to view the command prompt.

The code from the batch file is :

```
cd\
cd C:\Users\vinayak\
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\vinayak\Desktop\Pramod C - UI Path\UI_Path_Gen.jar"
 pause
```

I expected the command prompt to be open and waiting for any key to be pressed but instead the command prompt is not shown and i am unable to enter the key.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume either your task scheduler is not pointed at the batch file at all, or the task scheduler user does not have proper permissions to run the bat file. I was able to reproduce your issue by pointing to a batch file that isn't there.

Can you verify that it's pointed at the right file, and that it has permissions to run the bat file AND the java command?

Comment: I have added some screen shots(my batch process details and the task scheduler details) to my original question. Can you please help me further

Comment: Can you remove the java line, save the scheduler.bat file, and inside of Task Scheduler right click the task and click "Run" and let me know if it runs?

Comment: i have removed the line after which i tried to run the scheduler .The status for the scheduler has turned from ready to running but the command prompt is not seen.Just to be double sure , i checked the tasklist and found that there are instances of command prompt running with their respective process id, so i suspect the batch is executed and the command prompt is triggered , but it is in the background.

Comment: Yeah that's the exact same conclusion I've come to as a result of your "Run whether user is logged in or not". If you switch to "Run only when user is logged in" and re-run it, does that allow you to see your command prompt?

Comment: I tried changing the setting and i was able to view the command prompt as expected. Thanks for your help, but could you please help me with what impact would changing the setting have.

Comment: Task Scheduler WON'T run this if you're not logged into the user. I would test it by logging into this user, setting up a run-time for 1 minute from then, then switching (stay logged in, but just switching) users. Switch back after a minute or two to make sure it ran. I would recommend adding event logging to your bat file and logging in your java app to monitor its progress as well. Diving deep into either of these topics is beyond my knowledge, but this should help start you on your path though now that you know it's working!

Comment: Does this mean if i change the setting and the system runs out due to idle time , the user will be logged out and the batch will not execute?

Comment: Do you mean if the system locks? Or are you saying that your system automatically logs you out if you're idle? If it's the former, then I have to imagine a locked system will still run the task and you're fine. If your system is set up to automatically log you out after X minutes idle, then yes, your task will not run. I'd check and update your windows settings in this case

Comment: I meant the second scenario in which the system logs out after X minutes idle. If the batch will not run in this scenario , can any additional setting help to ensure this is achieved?

Comment: Yes, but that would necessarily cause your command prompt to no longer pop up as it will be running in background mode. You could have a separate task that monitors events and have the batch file trigger that event and tell you when it ran, but I unfortunately can't think of a way to have your cake and eat it too all in one task

Comment: Ok will try to find an alternative for this problem. Thanks for your suggestions.